# reading mail from rediffmail using imap_open() function

Tags: php, mail-server, imap-open

Can anyone tell me how do i connect to rediff mail server using imap_open() function in php.
i tried with the following code:

```
$this->conn = imap_open('{'.$this->server.'}INBOX', 'easyloanemi@rediffmail.com', 'password')or die(print_R(imap_errors()));
```

and got below error

Severity: Warning

Message: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.rediffmail.com/notls/norsh}INBOX

and the imap_errors() return

```
Array ( [0] => LOGIN failed: Login failed. Either your user name or your password was wrong. Please try again, and if the problem persists, please contact your system administrator. 
[1] => LOGIN failed: Login failed. Either your user name or your password was wrong. Please try again, and if the problem persists, please contact your system administrator. 
[2] => LOGIN failed: Login failed. Either your user name or your password was wrong. Please try again, and if the problem persists, please contact your system administrator. 
[3] => Too many login failures )
```

I am able to login if I go directly to rediffmail website using the credentials

Answer (score 0):

user / pass are wrong, try without @rediffmail.com or check login parameters of your messagerie to allow connect with imap. Else see how to login with SMTP.

Comment: tried without @rediffmail.com got --[CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)-- error